# Is there any way to move Devise's headers response to body?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, devise

In my Rails-api app I'am using `Devise` gem which when authenticating returns all crucial info (Access-Token, UID, Client etc) in Headers, like this:

```
Access-Token →DIbgreortZbCYKqzC8HdNg
Client →Y6J5oTIqS7Gc_-h9xynBQ
Uid →email2@example.com
```

I want those to be in the response Body. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Rails provides you with a request object so you can grab whatever you need out of the headers in your controller.

```
def some_action
     @mime_type = request.headers["Content-Type"] # => "text/plain"
     @token = request.headers["key-for-your-token-here"]
end
```

You can then either pass it to your view or you can insert it into the response body via `request.body`as you would insert any key/value pair into a hash.

Documentation for ActionDispatch::Request found here:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-headers

UPDATE:

Make a custom method and see how long it has to run to navigate the header hash.  If long you can use it to find the exact nesting of what you're looking for and change it.

```
def find_token(parent, request.headers)
  request.headers.each {|key, value|
    if value.is_a?(Hash) 
       find_token(key, value)
    elsif key == 'THE TOKEN KEY HERE'
       return value
    else
      next
    end 
  }
end
```

Comment: when I do `request.headers["access-token"]` it returns `nil`
but the output is correct with  `request.headers["Content-Type"]`

Comment: That means you're not getting the right key.  The key itself could be nested as well.  Add a puts statement for request.headers in your controller and paste it to your question so we can see.

Comment: The output looks looks like this. Can't access the token in any way
https://pp.vk.me/c638121/v638121746/239b4/PF4NFzGBTio.jpg

Comment: Ok now the hard part is finding how deeply it is nested.  At the very least it is @header[:access_token] however if that doesn't work you have to find out how many hashes/arrays it is inside and basically work your way to it.  For instance it could be response[:something][:another_array][:another_hash][:header][:access_token]

Comment: there's just no way to find how deeply it's nested. Spent 1.5 hrs on that

Comment: the question is about response headers not request headers